# Mathematica learning resource dealing with bayesian inference

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

Is there any good resource dealing with both *Mathematica* and bayesian inference?

Comment: http://www.astro.cornell.edu/staff/loredo/bayes/

Comment: http://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of only one reference: the book by Phil Gregory "Bayesian Logical Data Analysis for the Physical Sciences". I can recommend this book. It covers a great deal of Bayesian data analysis and includes many worked examples.

It is published by Cambridge University Press: http://bit.ly/1tdaYhG .
It is accompanied by a large(!) Mathematica notebook, which you can download from the Resources-tab at the same web page.

Comment: +1. Much needed advice since one has to really look hard to find something. There is also the [Mathematica Navigator](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&id=6CGod4o7yf8C&pg=PA1046#v=onepage&q&f=false).