# How to perform Bayesian optimization with Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, machine-learning

Does Mathematica have any Bayesian optimization methods for learning hyper-parameters?

> Practical Bayesian Optimization of Machine Learning Algorithms
>   Jasper Snoek, Hugo Larochelle and Ryan P. Adams
>   Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, 2012

For example, I'm using Whetlab to learn parameters in a computer vision problem. But I'd like to use Mathematica, seems like something that should be supported with all of Version 9's support for gaussian processes right?

Here is an example of bayesian optimization at work:

[image]

Comment: or bayesian regression for that matter!

Comment: There are very few pre-packed Bayesian expressions in Mathematica. I have recommended the book by Phil Gregory in another post ( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66140/mathematica-learning-resource-dealing-with-bayesian-inference/66376#66376 ). It comes with a large Mathematica notebook.